# Difference between solubility and dissolution?

Tags: solutions

How is *solubility* different from *dissolution*? And how are they both different from *solvation*?

Answer (score 11):

> **Solvation** [...] is the process of attraction and association of molecules of a solvent with molecules or ions of a solute. As ions dissolve in a solvent they spread out and become surrounded by solvent molecules.
>   [...]
>
> **Dissolution** is a kinetic process, and is quantified by its rate. **Solubility** quantifies the dynamic equilibrium state achieved when the rate of dissolution equals the rate of precipitation.

Quote from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvation).

Answer (score 1):

Solubility is a chemical property referring to the ability of a given substance, the solute, to dissolve in a solvent. Dissolution, or solvation, is the process by which a solute interacts with and becomes dissolved in a solvent due to an increase in stability.

Comment: This is in principle the same as Tschoppi already stated.

Answer (score 0):

Solubility is maximum amount of solute that will dissolve in a given solvent at a given temperature to form saturated solution. Dissociation is a more kinetic process which depend on lattice and hydration energy.

Answer (score 0):

• Dissolution is the process where a solute dissolves in a solvent to form a solution, whereas solubility is the outcome of dissolution.

• Solubility is a thermodynamic entity whereas dissolution is kinetic.

• Solubility is measured in mol/kg and dissolution is measured in mol/s

Answer (score 0):

solubility:

- the capacity of solute to be dissolved in a given amount of solvent (how many moles of solute are dissolved)
- solutes solubility is always questioned
- it is a thermodynamic process
- its unit is mol/kg

dissolution:

- rate of solute dissolving in a solution (how fast the solute dissolves)
- solute is always soluble
- it is a kinetic process
- its unit is mol/sec